# "Syntax error in constraint clause" MS Access creating a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep getting the syntax error in access when trying to add a foreign key to a table. The foreign key is LendorID and it is referenced in another table. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK_INVENTORY
(
CRN int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AuthorLastName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    AuthorFirstName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    BookTitle varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    LendorID varchar(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LENDOR_INFO(LendorID),
);
```

Here is my code for the table that contains LendorID:

```
CREATE TABLE LENDOR_INFO
(
    LendorID varchar(5)  NOT NULL,
    LendorLastName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LendorFirstName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LendorEmail varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (LendorID)
);
```

Comment: `LendorID varchar(5) REFERENCES LENDOR_INFO(LendorID)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!